# How to Unit Test CrudRepository without @DataJpaTest in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-data-jpa, crud-repository

I wanted to write unit test for the following UserRepository in Spring Framework application:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

But canFindUserByEmail() test fails because underTest is null

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository underTest;


    @Test
    public void canFindUserByEmail() {
        // given
        User expectedUser = new User();
        expectedUser.setEmail("user@gmail.com");
        underTest.save(expectedUser);

        // when
        final User actualUser = underTest.findByEmail(expectedUser.getEmail());

        // then
        assertThat(actualUser).isEqualTo(expectedUser);
    }
}
```

When I add the next annotations it works, but are they intended for integration testing, not for unit testing?

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration()
```

Thanks!

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` is used for test slices, which actually is a form of integration testing. So yes Spring will in fact use an actual in-mem db and will create the ApplicationContext.

Comment: Thanks! How to add this annotation to my application if my application doesn't support Spring Boot?

Comment: That is impossible because it's a Spring Boot annotation triggering certain Spring Boot autoconfiguration classes. It makes little sense to use it outside of a Spring Boot project.

Comment: Then how to test my repository without this annotation? Should I add manually in-mem database with Spring?

Comment: By bootstrapping the whole context. You need Spring Data JPA to be setup else there is nothing to test.